# How to convert two integer values into a floating number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So here is the scenario, I have two values:

```
var a=1
var b=23
```

I want a value like (a.b) 1.23:

```
var a=10
var b=45
```

I want a value like (a.b) 10.45

Is it possible? Then how?

Comment: What happens if `b` is not 2 digits?

Comment: Know that not all cents in decimal can be accurately expressed in floating point. eg. `0.10` is just as impossible to represent in float as `1/3` in decimal. When ignoring this how would it be if `b` is `123` and why is `a=10, b=4 => 10.45` where does the 5th cent come from?

Comment: I'd like to know how a question with such [demanding urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) got an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

```
var a=10; var b=45;
var result = +(a + '.' + b);
```

`+` operator is **unary** operator for converting a string into a number.
See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 10;
var b = 45;
var res = a + (b/100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine them into a string, and then run the result through [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp):

```
var a=1
var b=23

var result = parseFloat(a + "." + b);
```

Edit: As per @Vostrugin's comment, you can ensure the number of decimal places using `toFixed()`

```
parseFloat('0.0').toFixed(2) // this will give you 0.00
```

Comment: var a=0
var b=0
When i do parseFloat..it gives me 0 value..i want 0.00

Comment: @SunnyCoder, add .toFixed(2)

Comment: Hi @pabs123  if the a =5 and b=5 , it should give me 5.05 ..is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = a + "." + b;
alert(c);
```

Comment: According to my knowledge, I would assume, that the result in c is not a floating number, but a string.
Yet you can convert/cast it into a float by e.g. adding zero: var c = a + "." + b + 0; So I think the answer of @Agalo is a little more accurate.
Nevertheless this will work as well as JavaScript is not a strongly typed language.

Comment: What I provided him gives him exactly what he is looking for.  Combining two values separated by a period.  He never went into detail on what he needs this for.

Comment: he specifically said "into a floating number"

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is through string concatenation.

It would look like `+(a + "." + b)`

In JavaScript, a string added to a number becomes a string. A number appended to a string, and the string remains.

However, then we need to convert it to a number. We do that by either using `parseInt`, or `+`

Here is an example you can try for yourself

```js
var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function convertNumber() {
    result.innerHTML = (+(n1.value + "." + n2.value));
}
```

```css
#number-converter {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
Number 1: <input type="text" id="n1" />
Number 2: <input type="text" id="n2" />
<button id="number-converter" onclick="convertNumber()">Calculate Number</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: why are you grabbing all of these elements? we don't know that's how these numbers exist on a page, he just mentions two vars. This answer is overkill

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test=function(a,b){
  return parseFloat(a + "." + (b>10||b===0?b:(b+"5"))).toFixed(2);
};

console.log(test(1,23));

console.log(test(10,4));

console.log(test(0,0));

//That will always work


//THATS IF YOU WANT THE 10.45 ROUND EFFECT THAT YOU QUEST
```

Comment: if var a=0 & var b=0 ?i want result 0.00 ? will this work ?

Comment: @SunnyCoder updated with your solutions